# How do I add folders into an iOS application documents directory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sandbox, directory

How do I add folders into an iOS app documents directory? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most file operations are done via the `NSFileManager` class. To create a new directory use this method:

```
-[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]
```

Apple documentation here: [Apple reference docs -createDirectoryAtPath](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:)

Answer (score 6):

yes.

Though I suspect your question was 'how do I' instead of 'Can I'

Check out the [NSFileManager class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create folders.